# Ошибка CORS policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, nestjs

Пытаюсь отправить данные формы на сервер nestjs на другом порте, фронт запросы, которые я попробовал:

```
axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/auth',
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        data: { nickname: name, password: password } })
        
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth', data, {
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          }
        }).then(function (response: any) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error: any) {
          console.log(error);
        });

      await fetch("http://localhost:5000/auth", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
```

Также пытался конкретизировать адрес сервера, вместо "*".
Сервер принимает так:

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Post('auth')
  @Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost:3000')
  catchData(@Param('data') data: any): any {
    console.log('data:', data);
    return this.appService.catchData(data);
  }
}
```

Но я все равно получаю ошибку:

[image: Ошибка]

Подскажите в чем проблема.

Comment: Для начала уберите headers из запроса. Эти заголовки должен отправить сервер в ответе, а в запросе они бесполезны и даже вредны т.к. вызывают preflight запрос который вы не обрабатываете на сервере

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо, понял, но проблема актуальна.

Comment: Перед запуском сервера, Вам нужно включить CORS. https://docs.nestjs.com/security/cors

Comment: @KonstantinFedorov Спасибо, ошибка пропала, но почему то данные не ловятся, буду разбираться, добавьте ответ, приму.

Comment: Попробуйте не через Params, а через Body данные принимать. Вы же в теле запроса передаёте

Comment: @KonstantinFedorov Да, еще раз спасибо, все работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед запуском сервера, Вам нужно включить CORS. docs.nestjs.com/security/cors